# Stuck with VBA SumIf

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to work on this sumif code for a while but keep getting an error (Run Time Error 1004 'Unable to get the SumIfs property of the Worksheet Function class). anyone have any ideas as to why?

I am trying to match an ID that I have on column B (basically a table) and match it with all the IDs present on column F. If there are matches, then i want to take all the quantities/values the ID has and sum them. Then place the sum on column C next to the corresponding ID

```
lastrowB = cnCS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rngtotalvalue = cnCS.Range("B50:B" & lastrowB)
lastrow = cnCS.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set datarange = cnCS.Range("F3:T" & lastrow)

Dim rgColumnC As Range, n As Long
For Each rgColumnC In rngtotal.Rows

    Set columnB = cnCS.Range("S3:S" & lastrow)
    
    totalvalue = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(datarange, rngtotalvalue, columnB)
    rgColumnC.Cells(1, 2) = totalvalue
    
Next rgColumnC


Dim rgWeightRow As Range
For Each rgWeightRow In datarange.Rows

    sAccountNumber = rgWeightRow.Cells(1, 1)
    sEuro = rgWeightRow.Cells(1, 14)
    sTotalValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sAccountNumber, rngtotal, 2, False)
    sWeight = (sEuro / totalvalue)
    rgWeightRow.Cells(1, 15).Value = sWeight

Next rgWeightRow
```

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf` will not return a single value when you supply a range of cells.  You will need to iterate and only pass one value to the criteria at a time.

Comment: i have a list of value that i would like to pass through, so wouldnt doing it one at a time take a while?

Comment: Also, I just saw that your sum range is a 1D while you data is 2D, SUMIF will not do that.

Comment: If I were doing it I would store everything in variant arrays and loop those doing the math in another variant variable and then post the results.

Comment: thanks for the tip Scott! Unforunately, I am not too confident on creating that. do you have any pointers?

Comment: What are you actually trying to sum?

Comment: norie! great to hear from you. i am basically trying to take all of the unique IDs from a data set with over 7000 rows and sum all of their corresponding values (ID: 123456 has 20 corresponding rows with different values but  sums up to 1346436). i have 74 IDs and i thought it was best to use a sumif

Comment: @norie? @Scott?

Comment: Could you please complete your code. A lot of your variables is not present. For example what range is `rngtotal` and `DataRange`?

Comment: @wizhi sorry for the delay.. i  made the edits now

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach using a dictionary to track the sums:

```vb
Sub SumUp()
    
    Dim dict As Object, data As Range, rw As Range, k, v
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    Set data = Sheets("data").Range("A2:X7000") 'for example
    For Each rw In data.Rows
        k = rw.Columns("B").Value                 'id's in ColB
        v = rw.Columns("X").Value                 'values in ColX
        If Len(k) > 0 And IsNumeric(v) Then
            dict(k) = dict(k) + v
        End If
    Next rw
    
    'output the sums
    With Sheets("Summary").Range("A2")
        .Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
        .Offset(0, 1).Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.Items)
    End With

End Sub
```

EDIT: seems like this would be closer to what you want

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, addrB As String, addrF As String, addrS As String, frm As String
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    addrB = ws.Range("B50:B" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Address
    addrF = ws.Range("F3:F" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Address
    addrS = ws.Range("S3:S" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Address
    
    With ws.Range(addrB).Offset(0, 1)
        .FormulaArray = "=SUMIF(" & addrF & "," & addrB & "," & addrS & ")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi tim, thanks so much for the code! as of the moment, I am trying to match an ID that I have on column B (basically a table) and match it with all the IDs present on column F. If there are matches, then i want to take all the quantities/values the ID has and sum them. Then place the sum on column C next to the corresponding ID

Comment: Are the IDs in column B unique? Do they appear multiple times in column F? Which column do the values you want to sum come from?

Comment: Hi norie, the IDs in colum B are the unique IDs (removed duplicates) from column F. So yes they do appear multiple times in column F but they can have different values in column S. I am looking to get the sum of all the values with the same ID to be stored in column C